# Wildfly - logging into one file

Tags: wildfly

It seems my wildfly server produces separate log file for each day: like 
`server.log.2017-06-30  server.log.2017-07-06`. Is it possible to make it logging into one (always same) file?

Comment: @TT He called it a server and talked of server logging, hence my assumption it was a server. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

By default WildFly is configured to use a `periodic-rotating-file-handler` which rotates every day. If you don't want log rotation you can use a `file-handler` instead.

The following CLI commands will make the change to using a `file-handler`.

```
batch
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=FILE)
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:remove
/subsystem=logging/file-handler=FILE:add(named-formatter=PATTERN, append=true, autoflush=true, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=server.log})
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=FILE)
run-batch
```

One attribute to note is the `append` attribute. I've set it to `true` so that you won't lose any log messages on a reboot or when this command is executed. If you're not concerned about losing log messages you could set it to `false`.