# Need to add custom logs in hawtio

Tags: logging, hawtio

we are using hawtio for displaying dashboards on wildfly,  we are logging user activities in a seperate file,  we want to log user activity like login n logout which is being implemented LoginServlet of Hawtio. 
Can anyone help me understand how to add the custom logs for login and logout to the seperate user activities log file

Answer (score 0):

Turning on `DEBUG` level logging for `io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet`, `io.hawt.web.auth.LogoutServlet`, and `io.hawt.system.Authenticator` should give you login/logout activities in the log.

How to set up logging for specific categories is a matter of WildFly. Consult with other questions such as: [Wildfly - logging into one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037618/wildfly-logging-into-one-file)